# Consultar produtos que tenham o mesmo cod e colocar em um array

Tags: php, mysqli

Quero exibir os produtos que tenham o mesmo código de pedido, porém quando faço o select ele exibe apenas o primeiro produto que encontra com aquele código.

```
$prod = "SELECT * FROM produtos_pedido WHERE pedido_cod = $codPedido";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$prod);
$produtos=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
```

[image: Banco de dados tabela produtos_pedido]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código está certo, acontece que se sua query retorna mais de uma linha, você precisa chamar a função `mysqli_fetch_assoc` dentro de um laço, para pegar assim todas as linhas retornadas:

```
while ($produtos=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  //Código
}
```

---

Para colocar os resultados em um array, você pode optar por algo assim:

```
$produtos_pedido = [];

while ($produtos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  array_push($produtos_pedido, $produtos);
}
```

Sendo `$produtos_pedido` o array que vai conter todos os registros que a query retornou (linhas e colunas)

---

Se você pretende utilizar os dados durante o loop, no exemplo apenas exibir os valores:

```
while ($produtos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo "Código = " . $produtos["cod"];
    echo " Produto = " . $produtos["produto_cod"];
    echo " Quantidade = " . $produtos["quantidade"];
    echo " Pedido = " . $produtos["pedido_cod"];
    echo "\n";
}
```

---

> Veja um exemplo online:  http://tpcg.io/mTWZdhYB
>
> Documentação: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php